# Count how many times a Nurse washes their hand before patient contact: Is X before Y, group_by(ID)?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a set of observed behaviour of nurses conducting patient care and record what they touch or do. This might look like:

```
df<-data.frame(ActivityID=rep(1:3, each=3),
Action=c("Door", "Hygiene", "Patient", "Door", "Patient", "Door", "Door", "Patient", "Hygiene"))
```

I'd like to check whether they wash their hands before the first time they touch the patient for each ActivityID and count for how many ActivityID's this occurs. Essentially I'd like to know if X happens before Y for each activity.

My thought was to use which to find the first occurrence for both Patient and Hygiene:

```
require(dplyr)
a=df%>%
group_by(ActivityID) %>%
  which(Action=="Hygiene")

b=df%>%
group_by(ActivityID) %>%
  which(Action=="Patient")

which(a<b)
```

But this doesn't seem to work in pipe form and sometimes, they don't touch the patient. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can `hygiene` be more than once in a determined activity? Like having `Door, Hygiene, Patient,Door,Patient,Hygiene`.

Comment: Yes, usually it is because they will do it before touching the patient and just before leaving. In an ideal scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Total unique activities can be calculated using :

```
library(dplyr)
total_Activities <- n_distinct(df$ActivityID)
total_Activities
#[1] 3
```

We can write a function to check if hands were washed anytime before touching the Patient for first time:

```
hands_washed_before_touch <- function(x) {
    ind1 <- which(x == 'Hygiene')
    ind2 <- which(x == 'Patient')
    length(ind1) && length(ind2) && ind1[1] < ind2[1]
}
```

and use it by group :

```
df1 <- df %>% 
        group_by(ActivityID) %>% 
        summarise(hands_washed = hands_washed_before_touch(Action))
df1
# ActivityID hands_washed
#       <int> <lgl>       
#1          1 TRUE        
#2          2 FALSE       
#3          3 FALSE
```

To get count we can `sum` `hands_washed` column i.e `sum(df1$hands_washed)`.

Comment: Wow, this is neat, thank you! Just to clarify. The hygiene can be at any point before patient contact, not just the immediate previous thing they do. Can this be worked into your code please?

Comment: I updated the answer to make it more flexible. Can you check it now?

Comment: Thanks for such a quick reply. Yes, this works very nicely.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another alternative using `case_when` from `dplyr` package.

```
 library(dplyr)
  df1<-  df %>% 
        group_by(ActivityID) %>% 
        mutate(hands_washed = case_when(
            !any(Action == "Hygiene") ~ "False",
            min(c(which(Action == "Hygiene"), Inf)) > which.max(Action == "Patient")~ "False",
            TRUE ~ "True"))%>%
    ungroup()
    df1
    # A tibble: 9 x 3
    # Groups:   ActivityID [3]
    #  ActivityID Action  hands_washed
    #       <int> <fct>   <chr>       
    #1          1 Door    True        
    #2          1 Hygiene True        
    #3          1 Patient True        
    #4          2 Door    False       
    #5          2 Patient False       
    #6          2 Door    False       
    #7          3 Door    False       
    #8          3 Patient False       
    #9          3 Hygiene False
```

Comment: Thank you Sri. So to pull out the fraction of those that do wash their hands, would you do summarise(first(x) ())?

Comment: @HCAI This answer was framed based on the fact that for each `ActivityID`  there must be `Hygiene` preceding `patient`.  By first `hands_washed` do you mean, `Hygiene` should be the  first `Action` for each `Activity ID` ?

Comment: Not necessarily, only that hygiene must precede the first time they touch the patient. Normally the first action they do is rouch the door before any hygiene anyway.

Comment: Looking at the output you have, i would like the calculate the fraction of activities when they do wash their hands before (ie. TRUE)

Comment: You can try `df1 %>% group_by(hands_washed) %>% summarise(proportion = n()/nrow(df1))` where `df1` is the answer that I have provided. Remember to `ungroup` it in the end.

Comment: Hmm so this adds up all the TRUES and FALSES but not each ACTIVITYID has the same number of rows this skews the result. Right?

Comment: @HCAI Yes. If you want to get a specific new output, you can ask a new question. That might elicit more responses.

Comment: Thank you Sri. I believe it is intrinsic to this question rather than something new because the current output gives TRUE or FALSE for each row. I'm not sure how to use this.